# How do I type one letter at a time for an input in Python

Tags: python

I recently read about how to type one letter at a time in Python to look old school and cool using loops and time - however, my code has an input. Does anyone know how to do this for and input (in my code , "what is your name?")

I've tried changing the input name but has failed. The code simply prints it at once like usual

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for, I think it's a way to read characters as they are being typed before the user presses enter. Its possible, but cumbersome.

Comment: Based on "The code simply prints it at once like usual", I think the user is asking how to print a string one letter at a time.

Comment: @HBoi, could you help us out with a clarification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to do something that looks like this:

[image: Demo]

Then the easiest way is to do it as it was done back in the good old days. What happened then was that the program would send special codes to the terminal (which back then was a real physical device, not just a window), and the terminal would do whatever codes wanted. There were codes for moving the cursor around, changing colors, beeping and lots of other nifty stuff that you would need.

A common set of codes that still are in use today are known as the [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

There is an excellent package called [Colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama) for Python that does all of the heavy-lifting and that is cross-platform. I recommend using that.

Source code for the demo above:

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
import time

def print_old(message):
    print(Fore.GREEN, end='', flush=True)
    for c in message:
        print(c, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print(Style.RESET_ALL, end='', flush=True)

init()
print_old('What is your name? ')
name = input()
print_old('Nice to meet you %s\n' % name)
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, you can print each letter and use input at the end. 
Something like this:

```
output = "what is your name?"

for i in output:
    print(i, end='')
x = input()
```

`x` will be the string containing what the user inputs.
Imho, it's not cool, just redundant.

If you want a delay between the appearance of each letter, use the `time` module.

```
import sys
import time
output = "what is your name?"

for i in output:
    print(i, end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
x = input()
```

Note the use of `sys.stdout.flush()` to push each letter immediately in the output.

Answer (score 0):

This makes it look like what you're talking about

```
import time

output = "what is your name?"
blank = ""


for i in output:
    blank = blank + i
    print("\r"+blank, end='')
    time.sleep(0.1)
x = input()
```

The idea is to build larger and larger portions of your output and using the \r you replace the line in the console each time.  Waiting 0.1 seconds between loops adds to the effect